# What is the general name for these articles which feature lists?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns, terminology

Well, recently the internet has been taken by storm by articles such as: "20 Ways To Subtly...", "5 Things to Watch...", "15 things only a Pakistani..." etc,.

So, what do you call such features?

Comment: I'm really tempted to say [clickbait](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/clickbait). It's not exactly what you're looking for, but there's a significant amount of overlap with what you're looking for.

Comment: @SomethingDark Well, thank you for for telling me about clickbait, but, pus videos, articles objectifying women; they all form part of such a big family.

Answer (score 6):

**[Listicle](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/listicle)** 'an article structured in the form of a list, typically having some additional content relating to each item'

The word is of relatively recent coinage and is a portmanteau from 'list' and 'article'. 
(In my experience, usage is often slightly derogatory, but I have no cite for that.)

Comment: So, is this the generally accepted term?

Comment: 27-year-old American here, never heard that word in my life.

Comment: It is a term which I am familiar with in British English. As I say, it is a recent coinage, and it may turn out not to have staying power, but it is current and easy to find a definition for if you encountered it in the wild. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Listicle

Comment: 30-year old American here, I hear this word all the time.

Comment: Should I have mentioned being a 52 year old Scot?

Comment: It's not that recent.  In my recollection it became common when Buzzfeed was something of a phenomenon.

Comment: @stevesliva I'm 52 and in Scotland, I discovered Buzzfeed about a month ago :-/

Comment: I've not encountered this term before but I like it a lot.